# Getting a control position of a Java GUI application

Tags: c++, winapi, user-interface

Having a Java GUI application, I need to get the location of one of its buttons, so I'll be able to simulate a mouse click.

What is the most straightforward way of doing this **from a C++/WinAPI application**?

I need to embed this solution into a downloadable application, so preferably it should not require using a multimegabyte library.

For example, having an app similar to this (screenshot from Wikipedia):

[image: Screenshot of a GUI app]

How can I get the RECT of the button?